# i am getting issue while start tomcat server

Tags: jersey

I am new to jersey multi part. While i am starting the tomcat server getting issue.

```
@POST
            @Path("/uploadImagesUsingJersey")
            @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            @Produces("text/plain")
            public Response uploadImages(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws IOException{
                 String uploadedFileLocation = (String) session.getServletContext().getAttribute("ProfilePhotoPath");
                 uploadedFileLocation=uploadedFileLocation+236+"/"+fileDetail.getName();
                 writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

                    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
                 employeeVO=new EmployeeInformationVO();
                 employeeVO=(EmployeeInformationVO) CacheAction.getById(EmployeeInformationVO.class,236);
                 employeeVO.setPhotoPath(236+"/"+fileDetail.getFileName());
                 int result=CacheAction.commonAddOrUpdate(employeeVO);
                 return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();  
            }
```

I am using this kind Of jar:
    1)jersey-multipart-1.8-ea03.jar
    2)mimepull-1.8-sources.jar
    3)jersey-server-1.8.jar
    4)jersey-bundle-1.8.jar

And i am getting this kind of issue:
INFO: Provider classes found:

```
  class com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter
Nov 13, 2016 10:45:15 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:39 PM'
Nov 13, 2016 10:45:17 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.hrm.jersey.action.MyServiceAction.uploadImages(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.io.IOException at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.hrm.jersey.action.MyServiceAction.uploadImages(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.io.IOException at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.hrm.jersey.action.MyServiceAction.uploadImages(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.io.IOException, annotated with POST of resource, class com.hrm.jersey.action.MyServiceAction, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Nov 13, 2016 10:45:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
```